# Print different value that is stored in MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In MySQL table with myISAM I have a integer value ex.011. When I query in Python it prints me value 11 removing 0 before number. It should print the exact value that is stored in DB ex. 011 instead of 11. Any help ?

Comment: Is it an integer or a string?  If it is an integer, it doesn't have 0 padding.  Where are you seeing the value listed as `011`?  You probably have a different data type than you think, or your client is adding padding without you knowing.

Comment: type is Integer:  'id_order_ticket int(3) ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,' and I see in mysql db that it is ex. 011. I am using SQLAlchemy query: 'ast_order_ticket = self.session.query(OrderTicketNumber).order_by(OrderTicketNumber.id_order.desc()).first()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be, simple zero filling is OK in this case?

```
>>> print str(11).zfill(3)
011
```

As I understood, it's additional part of number. If its length is not constant, you need to change data type in DB to VARCHAR.

Comment: AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'zfill'

Comment: @Fi3n1k, check that you wrote `str(11).zfill(3)` instead of `long(11).zfill(3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your column is an `int`, so MySQLdb gives you an integer value back in the query result.  However, I think you should be able to write a mySQLdb result set wrapper (or maybe find one someone else already wrote) that inspects the flags set on the columns of the result set and casts to a string appropriately.

Look at `cursor.description` and `cursor.description_flags` as well as PEP-249.  I think (ie I have not actually tried it) something along the lines of the following should get you started:

```
def get_result_set_with_db_specified_formatting(cursor):
    integer_field_types = (MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.TINY,
                           MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.SHORT,
                           MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.LONG,
                           MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.LONGLONG,
                           MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE.INT24)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        for index, value in enumerate(row):
            value = str(value)
            if (cursor.description[index][1] in integer_field_types
                and cursor.description_flags[index] & MySQLdb.constants.FLAG.ZEROFILL):
                if len(value) < cursor.description[index][2]:
                    value = ('0' * (cursor.description[index][2] - len(value))) + value
            row[index] = value
    return rows
```